# Install gem bundles to ./vendor/bundle unless otherwise specified

Tags: ruby, bundler

I don't want my gems used in development clutter up my system. 
I often happen to forget to add the install path to `bundle install` resulting in bundle automatically being installed in the global gem repository.

How can I make bundler install gems to automatically install gems to to `./vendor/bundle` when run without the `--path` parameter?

Right now I am using a shell alias to get the desired result, but I have a hunch that there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the bundle for that in following way,

```
bundle config  path "vendor/bundle"
```

will set the BUNDLE_PATH which is installation path for gems

Checkout this link for more details http://bundler.io/v1.2/bundle_config.html

But on production, using capistrano, `bundle install` runs with option `--deployment` which automatically deploys to `vendor/*`